# UnicodeDecodeError in bs4 Python 3.4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a part of code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,10):
    print(str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("downloads/" + str(i) + ".html","rt"), 'html.parser')
    text1 = soup.find_all("div", class_="content html_format")
    text1 = text1[0].get_text()
    print(text1)
```

After executing I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "classifier1.py", line 6, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("downloads/" + str(i) + ".html","rt"), 'html.parser')
File "C:\Users\K18\Desktop\redictgames\classifier\bs4\__init__.py", line 175, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
File "C:\python34\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98
in position 11152: character maps to <undefined>
```

I was tried 'rb' and 'r' modes too, but this doesn't work...

In the files I have articles with Russian words.

Few days ago that was working perfectly

Comment: Yes, I was trying that too, it's seems to be not working...

Comment: You need to manually deal with the character encoding. Read here for reference: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings

Comment: When I trying to get original encoding, I get an None